# Проверка на соответствие имени и пароля

Tags: php, password

Есть проверка соответствия имени и пароля  на `php`.Принцип такой: если имя есть в файле(хранение имён и паролей в `json` файле) то проверить соответствует ли введенный пароль тому, что записан.

```
$file = "../data/users.json";

$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

$users = array();

if(is_array($json_array)) {
    $users = $json_array;
}

if(isset($users[$name])) {
    if($users[$name]["pass"] !== $password ){
        http_response_code(400);
    }
} 
else {
    $users[] = array("name" => $name, "pass" => $password, "id" => $i);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        $users[$key]["id"] = $i;
        $i++;
    }

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

А вот так записано в файле

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qwe",
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

В любом случае, когда я ввожу имя которое уже есть и пароль который ему не соответствует скрипт записывает это как новую пару.

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qwe",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "qwe",
        "pass": "qweqwe",
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: `isset($users[$name])` будет всегда false, потому что `$users` это массив, который имеет только числовые ключи (0, 1, 2 итд)

Comment: А не опасно хранить пароли в обычном `JSON` файле?

Comment: Может так? `isset($users[0])`

Comment: @erm это просто задание, в реальных условиях это использоваться не будет. Нет, не работает

Comment: В примере нет ни строчки, которые собственно записывают обратно в json. Надобы узнать в какой момент и что пишет

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Добавил в вопрос запись.

Comment: а. ну выше правильно написали, что if(isset($users[$name])) всегда false, поэтому выполняется else, где запись новой пары

Comment: @DmitryKozlov   ну это понятно, как мне исправить то это?

Comment: либо использовать логин как идентификатор в json, тогда будет считываться массив с ключами-логинами. Либо после чтения текущего массива, в цикле переписать его в другой массив с ключом логином, а только после этого проверять. Либо перебирать массив, пока не наткнетесь на нужный логин.

Answer (score 1):

У вас после того, как вы выполняете **json_decode()** и записи его в переменную $users типа массив, создается ключ типа инт и его значение - это объект!

Когда вы делаете проверку:

```
$users[$name]
```

Вы ничего не можете проверить, т.к. нужно обращаться так:

```
$users[0]->name
```

Где **[0]** - это номер элемента массива $users

Посмотрите как нужно обращаться к вашему массиву:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'));
$password = 'qwe';

$users = array();

if(is_array($json_array)) {
    $users = $json_array;
}

if(isset($users[0]->name)) {
    if($users[0]->pass !== $password ){
        http_response_code(400);
    }
}
```

Ну а вообще, это нужно будет делать в цикле, перебирать массив в поиске конкретного значения, например, имени. И вообще, дело конечно ваше, но нужно рационально использовать то, что было придуманно для тех или иных целей, например в json файле не хранят пароли, по крайней мере, в моем мире!)

Comment: Ваш  вариант не помог

Comment: @Максим Буяков А это не решение вашей проблемы, это сообщение о том, на что вам нужно обратить своё внимание!